# intuition behind an identity related to fourier transforms

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I saw the proof of this identity in  [a question about Fourier transforms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836639/a-question-about-fourier-transforms) :

$F(f(−t))w=F(f(t))(−w)$

Can someone give the intuition behind it ?

What I understand of Fourier transform of a function at a point $w$ is that : it
gives the amplitude of the wave of frequency $w$ in the fourier series of the function $f(t)$. When we flip the function why should there be a change of sign in the frequency ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Fourier transform gives complex-valued frequencies.  These are $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\omega \theta}$ for various values of $\omega$.  If $\omega$ is positive, these circulate anti-clockwise in the complex plane.  If $\omega$ is negative, these circulate clockwise in the complex plane.

What the identity you call out is saying is that under time reversal the two types of circulation are swapped.

Comment: Thank you. I want to learn in detail about "complex valued frequencies". Can you suggest any place ?

Comment: I would start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal#Examples

Comment: I would also look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor_%28sine_waves%29 , which has a helpful animation.